# Submitting a Spark Job using Cloudera Manager

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

Is there a way that I can submit a Spark Job using the Cloudera Manager?

In the Cloudera tutorial [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cm_qs_quick_start.html#cmig_topic_6_5) they say that "Log into a cluster host", 
but I don't know how to do that in the Cloudera Manager.

Comment: This one is helpful -https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_apps.html

Comment: I have read that tutorial, but it is only a normal Spark Submission using Terminal. I am given a Cloudera Manager page and don't know how I  can start a terminal from there, or connect my Terminal to it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that "Log into a cluster host" in the documentation [1] means, logging in to the host through the terminal only.

For your understanding, I would say, "Run the Hadoop PiEstimator example" is the next step which is a terminal command.

However, the progress and the status of the job that is submitted through the terminal is very much visible in the Cloudera Manager, as mentioned in the doc.

**In short, submitting a Spark job from Cloudera Manager is not possible.**

[1] https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cm_qs_quick_start.html#cmig_topic_6_5